# How to add values to array and getback in java?

Tags: java, arrays

How do i add the value of numOne given below to an array so that when i need a before value i can take from that array. On every time i click operator i need to store the value in array before resetting number.

```
public void onClickOperator(View v){
    Button op = (Button) v;
        if (stxtOutput != "") {
            if (!opt) {
                if (current_operator == "") {
                    stxtInput += op.getText();
                    num1 = "";
                    numOne = 0.0;
                    Result = pt;
                    stxtOutput = format.format(pt);
                    current_operator += op.getText().toString();
                    opt = true;
                    decimal = false;
                    update();
```

i have tried to add but got error,

```
ArrayList<Double> numb;
numb = new ArrayList<>();
numb.add(numOne);
```

and if the last value stored numb.add(i) i need to get the value of before value i-1

Comment: What kind of error are you getting and can you please elaborate your problem in more detailed way?

Comment: cannot add to array list

Comment: What is the error that you are getting when u store in inside numb arraylist? What is the datatype of numOne?

Comment: Note that you are comparing strings with `==`. That is a problem on its own. See [How do I compare strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Double data type. app crashes on getting value from optr.get(i). i think i need to use for loop but dont know how to use to add and get data

Comment: @MCEmperor That works completely fine without any error my problem is that i need to add the value of numOne to array onClickoperator and i need to get previous and previous numbers

Comment: @AjayVaidhyanathan, do you create your array list each time before adding the `numOne`?

Comment: You mentioned _app crashes on getting value from optr.get(i)_  Will you provide a code referring this variable `optr` ?

Comment: @AjayVaidhyanathan Maybe in your case, but that's coincidence.